# Dedekind property of Real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

If $X$ And $Y$ are two non empty subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ such that

1. $X\cup Y=\Bbb{R}$
2. Every member of $X$ is less than Every member of $Y$
   Then either $X$ has a maximum or $Y$ has a minimum .

How can I prove this **assuming only *lub* property of real numbers** and further how can I get *lub* property using this and hence show *lub* property and **Dedekind property** are equivalent?

Comment: Do you know/understand  the lub property? Do you observe that the set $X$ is bounded above? Proceed with this information.

Comment: Read the exact wording of the lub property. Does that apply directly to one of the three sets mentioned in this problem? If so, applying it might be a good place to start.

Comment: To prove Lub via Dedekind you need to start with some non-empty set $A$ bounded by some number say $K$. Now let $Y$ be the set of all possible bounds of $A$. Can you proceed further?

Comment: The problems in your question are easy and don't try to think too hard about them. Solution will follow just with this confidence and the information in previous comments.